# How to get the following two lists from a json?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to parse a json with the following structure:

```
{"Question":["what is this?","this is another question"], "Topic": ["Web pages","another topic"]}
```

I would like to get two lists,

```
questions=["what is this?","this is another question"]
topics=["Web pages","another topic"]
```

Since I am a beginner parsing a json I was not able I tried:

```
>>> with open('stack.json','r') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
>>> for element in data:
...     print(element)
...
```

However I got just:

```
Question
Topic
```

So I Would like to appreciate support to get the previous two lists.

Comment: `for element in data.values():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the elements you must use the keys of the dictionary

```
import json

with open('stack.json','r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    questions=data["Question"]
    topics=data['Topic']
    print(questions)
    print(topics)
```

output:

```
['what is this?', 'this is another question']
['Web pages', 'another topic']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot now I understand how to parse jsons.